# Directory Structure for Importing Python Package using __init__.py

Tags: python, python-import

I've got a python project (projectA), which I've included as a git submodule in a separate project (projectB) as a subfolder. The structure is laid out as

```
projectB/
  projectB_file.py
  projectA/        (repository)
    projectA/      (source code)
      module1/
        file1.py   (contains Class1)
      file2.py     (contains Class2)
    tests/
      test_file1.py
```

I'm trying to figure out how to layout `__init__.py` files so in `projectB_file.py` I can import `Class1` and `Class2` as

```
from projectA.module1 import Class1
from projectA import Class2
```

Comment: I think the "right" answer is to put `projectB/projectA` into your module search path, then the imports as you've written them should just work. Without the path manipulation, you'll need `projectA.projectA.module1` and so on.

Comment: Ah, hey that does help! I didn't consider that. That's much nicer, as I'm trying to figure out how to make projectA into a proper python package eventually, and wouldnt need that top level `__init__.py`. I just wish PyCharm would know what I'm doing and tab complete from projectA when using sys.path

Comment: Actually marking the top level projectA/ as a source directory in PyCharm also takes care of that issue, so I'm set! If you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having the top level `projectA` part of the import will be a mistake. That will require you to write your imports with `projectA` duplicated (e.g. `import projectA.projectA.module1.file1`).

Instead, you should add the top `projectA` folder to the module search path in some way (either as part of an install script for `projectB`, or with a setting in your IDE). That way, `projectA` as a top-level name will refer to the inner folder, which you actually intend to be the `projectA` package.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an `__init__.py` in each subdirectory you want to treat as a package.  Which in your case means one in:

- `projectA`
- `projectA/projectA`
- `projectA/projectA/module1`
- `projectA/projectA/tests`

It would definitely be better you could lose that first `projectA` folder.

Comment: Not really sure how to do that, projectA is it's own separate repository. I have the subdirectory to place the actual project code apart from docs/ and tests/ etc. 

And including __init__.py everywhere doesn't quite do the trick. As it means including `from projectA.projectA.module1.file1 import Class1`

Comment: @abnowack: If `projectA` is a separate project, why do you have it under `projectB`?

Comment: projectA is a generic library for interpreting a dataset I've written, projectB is a specific analysis I am doing for a paper.

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoying issue. The main approach I use is to edit the PYTHONPATH. This is essentially how I do it.

```
ProjectB/                   # Main Repository
    projectb/               # Package/library
        __init__.py
        projectB_file.py
    docs/
    tests/
    setup.py                # Setup file to distribute the library
    freeze.py               # CX_Freeze file to make executables

    ProjectA/               # Subrepository
        projecta/           # Package/library
            __init__.py
            projectA_file.py
            file2.py
            submodule/
                __init__.py
                file3.py
        pa_module1/         # Additional package/library in 1 project
            __init__.py
            file1.py
        docs/
        tests/
        setup.py
```

With this setup I have to edit the python path before running ProjectB's code. I use this structure, because it is easier for deployment and distribution. The subrepository helps track the version of ProjectA for each release of ProjectB.

```
cd ProjectB
export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}:${PWD}/ProjectA
python projectb/projectB_file.py
```

projectB_file.py

```
from projecta import projectA_file
```

This is for my development environment. For a release environment someone would install with the below code.

```
# Need a correct setup.py to handle 2 packages for pa_module1 and projecta
pip install ProjectA (install projecta to site-packages) 
cd ..
pip install ProjectB (install projectb to site-packages)
```

This means projectb and projecta are in site packages. From there any file can simply

```
from projectb import projectB_file
from projecta import projectA_file, file2
from pa_module1 import file1

# Personally I don't like imports that use project.sub.sub.sub ...
# I have seen it cause import confusion and problems, but it is useful in some situations.
from projecta.submodule import file3

#import projecta.projectA_file
#import projecta # if __init__.py has import code

file1.Class1()
file2.Class2()
file3.Class3()
```

Additionally with pip you can install a library as a developer environment which links to the real project directory instead of copying files to site-packages.

```
pip install -e ProjectA
```